# How to use php7.0-fpm and php5.6-fpm concurrently on same server, but different vhosts?

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, php-fpm

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache 2.4.29

I used a guide to install php7.0-fpm and get my server set up on HTTP/2:

[How to Enable HTTP/2 in Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://techwombat.com/enable-http2-apache-ubuntu-16-04/)

These are the changes made based on the guide:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install php7.0-fpm
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
sudo a2enconf php7.0-fpm
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_event
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

However, I have one old site that is not compatible with PHP 7.0. Instead, I need just this one site to run on PHP 5.6. I tried installing and enabling `php5.6-fpm` based on various guides on the internet, but can't get it working.

I would like to install `php5.6-fpm` (or whatever 5.6 version works), and add a few lines to the Virtual Host file or `.htaccess` (whichever is easiest), and have just this one site work with `php5.6-fpm` without a huge overhaul project. At the same time, I don't want to change or mess up anything with my PHP 7.0 sites.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `php5.6-fpm` package:

```
sudo apt install php5.6-fpm
```

Add these lines to the Virtual Host file of the old site:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```